# How to display search results using selenium and GeckoDriver?

Tags: selenium, geckodriver

I'm trying to print search results of DuckDuckgo using a headless WebDriver and Selenium. However, I cannot locate the DOM elements referring to the search results no matter what ID or class name I search for and no matter how long I wait for it to load.

Here's the code:

```
opts = Options()
opts.headless = False
browser = Firefox(options=opts)

browser.get('https://duckduckgo.com')
search = browser.find_element_by_id('search_form_input_homepage')
search.send_keys("testing")
search.submit()

# wait for URL to change with 15 seconds timeout
WebDriverWait(browser, 15).until(EC.url_changes(browser.current_url))
print(browser.current_url)

results = WebDriverWait(browser,10)
  .until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"links")))

time.sleep(10)
results = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('result results_links_deep highlight_d result--url-above-snippet') # I tried many other ID's and class names
print(results) # prints []
```

I'm starting to suspect there is some trickery to avoid web scraping in DuckDuckGo. Does anyone has a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed to use cssSelector then it works.I use java, not python.

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(
     By.cssSelector(".result.results_links_deep.highlight_d.result--url-above-snippet"));
System.out.println(elements.size());
//10
```

Comment: No it does not work in headless mode (firefox) try it out by yourself

Comment: I still get the same result using headless mode. [image](https://prnt.sc/15y1wzy)

Comment: This is strange, I do see that you are getting `10`, but the same code is showing 0 in my local.

Comment: @cruisepandey I've also noticed that the class of the div that encloses each one of the results changes from "results js-results" in a standard browser to "results js-invisible" when I'm using the headless geckodriver

Comment: @lucasnguyen17 The code works with the css selector. Thanks! Do you have any idea why it doesn't work the other way?